# How do I set up a test duplicate of a Django and Postgresql based web application?

Tags: django, testing, postgresql

Not sure if this is an excessively broad and newbie-ish question for Stack Overflow but here goes:

I paid someone else to build a web application for me and now I want to tweak certain aspects of it myself. I learn best by trial and error – changing stuff and seeing what happens. Obviously that's not a great way to treat a live site, so I need to duplicate the site on some kind of test server which I can play with without fear of the consequences.

Unfortunately the closest I've come to programming has been creating ActionScript-based websites. I've never touched a database. So I really don't know where to start with setting up a test server.

I would really appreciate any advice about where to start. I am completely ignorant and lost here.

The web application is built in python/django using a Postgresql database. I use Mac OS X 10.6 if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 4):

You can run the site locally on your Mac. See the [installation documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/intro/install/#intro-install) for details on how to install Django and set it up to work with Postgres, then you can run the site just by going into the directory that contains the `manage.py` file and running `python manage.py runserver`.

The site will now be available in your browser by going to http://127.0.0.1:8000/